# Segmentation Fault using ttf library SDL C

Tags: c, sdl, truetype

I'm trying to put text on a window with sdl using C.
I'm following this
[tutorial.](http://programmersranch.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/sdl2-displaying-text-with-sdlttf.html)
If I follow step by step, after he initialise the surface:

```
 SDL_Color color = { 255, 255, 255 };
 SDL_Surface * surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,"Welcome to Programmer's Ranch", color);
```

I get segmentation Fault.
So at this point my code is this:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int quit = 0;
    SDL_Event event;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    TTF_Init(); //Initialise ttf library

    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL_ttf in SDL2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);
    SDL_Renderer * renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    TTF_Font * font = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf", 25);//Load text(to put after renderere initialisation!)The first is the path to the TrueType Font (TTF) that it needs to load. The second is the font size (in points, not pixels). In this case we're loading Arial with a size of 25.
    SDL_Color color = { 255, 255, 255 };
    SDL_Surface * surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, "Welcome to Programmer's Ranch", color);

    while (!quit)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);

        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
            quit = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

while his entire source code is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/dandago/gigilabs/src/8915845ffec6663cb64d67309cb13c6304ee4ca2/Sdl2Ttf/Sdl2Ttf/main.cpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default), but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: You should be checking return values of function calls. In particular, were calls to `SDL_Init()` and `TTF_Init()` successful? What about `TTF_OpenFont()`?

Answer (score 0):

**It is most likely that the path to `arial.ttf` is wrong. Make sure you include the full path of that file from the root project directory.**

What you should have doing is adding exception handlers every time you initiate or load something in [sdl](/questions/tagged/sdl)/[sdl-2](/questions/tagged/sdl-2). For example:

```
#include <stdexcept>

try
{
    TTF_Font * font = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf", 25);
    if (font == NULL)
    {
        throw(::std::runtime_error("Font failed to load! ERROR: "));
    }
}
catch (std::runtime_error const& msg)
{
    printf("%s", msg.what());
    if (SDL_GetError() != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", SDL_GetError());
    }
    if (TTF_GetError() != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", TTF_GetError());
    }
}
```